# org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

From controller I am sending BinderPlaceOrder object like this

```
model.addAttribute("addNewBinderPlaceOrder", new BinderPlaceOrder());
```

My Thymeleaf page is,

```html
<form class="addBinderPlaceOrderForm" role="form" action="#" th:action="@{/binderPlaceOrder/new-binderPlaceOrder}" th:object="${addNewBinderPlaceOrder}" method="post">      
  
  <div class="form-group">
        <label>Book</label>
        <select class="form-control" th:field="*{binderOrderItemDetails.book}">
            <option th:if="${book} == null" value=" " >Select Book</option>
            <option th:each="book : ${allBook}"
                    th:value="${book.id}"
                    th:text="${book.name}">
            </option>
        </select>
    </div> 
  
  <form>
```

Here is the controller,

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/binderPlaceOrder")
public class BinderPlaceOrderController{

@Autowired
BinderPlaceOrderService binderPlaceOrderService;

@Autowired
BookService bookService;

@RequestMapping(value="/new-binderPlaceOrder", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newBinderPlaceOrder(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("addNewBinderPlaceOrder", new BinderPlaceOrder());

    model.addAttribute("allBook", bookService.getAllBooks();

    model.addAttribute("addNewBinderOrderItemDetails", new BinderOrderItemDetails());

    return "user/binderPlaceOrder/new";
}
}
```

During run time I get the below error

> org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'binderOrderItemDetails.book' of bean class [PublisherInventory.model.user.BinderPlaceOrder]: Bean property 'binderOrderItemDetails.book' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Below are the classes.

Please note, every class has their own Id property along with other properties. For readability those are omitted.

Here is BinderPlaceOrder Class,

```
@Entity
public class BinderPlaceOrder implements Comparator<BinderPlaceOrder> {    

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "binderPlaceOrder", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<BinderOrderItemDetails> binderOrderItemDetails;   

public List<BinderOrderItemDetails> getBinderOrderItemDetails() {
    return binderOrderItemDetails;
}

public void setBinderOrderItemDetails(List<BinderOrderItemDetails> binderOrderItemDetails) {
    this.binderOrderItemDetails = binderOrderItemDetails;
}

}
```

Here is BinderOrderItemDetails class

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class BinderOrderItemDetails {

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="bookId")
private Book book;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="binderPlaceOrderId")
private BinderPlaceOrder binderPlaceOrder;       

public Book getBook() { return book; }

public void setBook(Book book) { this.book = book; }    

public BinderPlaceOrder getBinderPlaceOrder() { return binderPlaceOrder; }

public void setBinderPlaceOrder(BinderPlaceOrder binderPlaceOrder) {
 this.binderPlaceOrder = binderPlaceOrder; }    
}
```

Here is the Book Class

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Book implements Comparator<Book> {

@Column(name = "name")
@NotNull
@NotBlank 
private String name;

public String getName() {  return name; }
public void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}    
}
```

Can you please tell me of what I am doing wrong or how it can be solved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your controller and method?

Comment: @kuhajeyan, controller added.

Comment: binderOrderItemDetails is of type `List`. `List` doesn't have a `book` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JBNizet pointed out, your **BinderPlaceOrder** has

```
public List<BinderOrderItemDetails> getBinderOrderItemDetails() {
    return binderOrderItemDetails;
}
```

which is a list, hence

```
th:field="*{binderOrderItemDetails.book}"
```

would not be correct,

but say you want to insert the first element,

```
 th:field="${binderOrderItemDetails[0].book}"
```

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that.